# By row, get mean count of number of columns between values of x

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a data.frame that contains several columns (i.e. `V1`...`Vn+1`) that have a value of 1 or 0, each column is a timestep.

I want to know the average `time` (# of columns) between values of 1. With a sequence of `1 1 1 1 1 1` having a value of `1`.

At the moment the way I can think to possibly compute this would to be to calculate the mean count (+1) of 0s between 1s, but it is flawed.

For example, a row that had these values `1 0 0 1 0 1` would have the result `2.5` (`2 + 1` = `3`; `3/2` = `1.5`; `1.5` + `1` = `2.5`).

However, if the sequence begins or ends with 0s the results for this results should be calculated without them. For example, `0 1 0 0 1 1` would be computed as `1 0 0 1 1` with a result of `3`.

*Flawed* e.g. `1 0 1 1 0 0` would be computed as `1 0 1 1` resulting in `2`, **but** this would not be the desired result (`1.5`)

Is there a way to count the the numbers of columns between values of `1` by row, considering the issues with starting or ending with zeros?

```
# example data.frame with desired result
df <- structure(list(Trial = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Location = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Position = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), V1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), V4 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V5 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    Result = c(1, 3, 2, NA, 1, 2.5, 3, 1.5)), .Names = c("Trial", 
"Location", "Position", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "Result"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df1 <- df[,4:9]

#This code `apply(df1,1,function(x) which(rev(x)==1)[1])) calculates the number of columns back until a value of 1, or forward without `rev`. But this doesn't quite help with the flaw.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the range between the first and last 1 value is `k` and the total number of 1s in that range is `n`, then the average gap is `(k-1)/(n-1)`. You can compute this with:

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
  w <- which(x == 1)
  if (length(w) <= 1) NA
  else diff(range(w)) / (length(w)-1)
})
# [1] 1.0 2.0 2.0  NA 1.0 2.5 3.0 1.5
```

Comment: Nice approach; another view of this could be `mdf1 = as.matrix(df1); (max.col(mdf1, "last") - max.col(mdf1, "first")) / (rowSums(mdf1) - 1)` and insert `NA`s appropriately.